# Why stackoverflow error for multipal object creation

Tags: out-of-memory, stack-overflow

I have below code and it complies fine. On run time it gives Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError.
The reason could be recursive object creation.
But my question is in this case we should get OutOfMemory Error. Then why we are getting StackOverflowError.

```
public class MainClass {
    MainClass m = new MainClass();
    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
        MainClass mc = new MainClass();
        mc.getHello();
    }
    public void getHello(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because your constructor calls itself.

That's the definition of a stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks Schabse. but then why not OutOfMemory error because of continues object creation. Even i tried writing print statements in constructor but its not getting displayed.

Comment: @Bhushan: No; each object is only allocated as part of the constructor.  You don't see that message because the field initializer runs before the constructor body.